# How to adjust multiSortLimit in grid

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs6-classic

I have a grid with the multiColumnSort property to be able to order the data depending on the columns which were clicked. The problem is that I can only have 3 columns selected. In the ExtJS docs is a hint which indicates to use the 'Ext.util.Collection' to adjust the multiSortLimit property. However, I do not know how to use the 'Ext.util.Collection' for the grid.

The Link to the docs: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.util.Collection.html#cfg-multiSortLimit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference to `Ext.util.Collection` in `Store`.

You can do it by : `store.getData()` and next use `setMultiSortLimit` on it to change `multiSortLimit`.

```
store.getData().setMultiSortLimit(5);
```

Comment: Thanks Dude! you really helped me out!